# What impact have different types of border-handling on high pass or low pass filtering?

Tags: image-processing, lowpass-filter, opencv, highpass-filter

When high or low pass filters are being applied to an (grayscale) image, the borders need to be handled separately. They could be filled with 0's or 255's (b/w), repeat the nearest pixel value, or even the image could be repeated.

How do the different border-handling-methods impact the result of he filtering operations? What are the pro's and con's of using one method over an other with a HPF to improve the edges in a picture or a LPF to blur it?

OpenCV for example has various [BorderTypes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5) like `BORDER_REPLICATE` or `BORDER_CONSTANT` but I can't find any information about what happens when I use one of them with a HPF or LPF.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the kind of filter and the use/expectations of its output.

For a lowpass filter where you want to look at a smoothed waveform, perhaps replicating the first sample is a good solution.

For a highpass filter where you want to detect edges, the above solution would still introduce a non-smooth derivative. So perhaps mirroring and flipping is a good solution.

For higher-order applications where you want smoothness/continuity in higher order derivatives? I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

HPF or LPF linear operators. It means that an operation at pixel position *i*, *j* will only be affected by neighbors within the window size of your filter. Pixels outside the filter will not play a role - in other words, the effects of any filtering operation is localized around its support. Typically, if the image size post filtering is not a concern, we 0 pad an image and crop out the contents near the border with a size equal to half the filter window. To maintain the same size, it is advisable to replicate border values.

Comment: A recursive (iir-) filter is linear but will in principle have infinite support, though.